# if POST submits everytime you load page

Tags: php

I am trying to make a simple reservation form in PHP. But everytime I click on the page in the menu, it inserts the empty fields in the database. I can't seem to find the problem.

**PHP CODE:**

```
    if ($_POST['submit'])
    {
        $navn = $_POST['navn'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $mobil = $_POST['mobil'];
        $antal = $_POST['antal'];
        $dato = $_POST['dato'];
        $tidspunkt = $_POST['tidspunkt'];
        $besked = $_POST['besked'];
    }

    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'emil');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO reserver VALUES ( '', '$navn', '$email', '$mobil', '$antal', '$dato', '$tidspunkt', '$besked' )";
    $db->query($sql);


?>
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
        <input class="half" type="text" name="navn" placeholder="Indtast dit navn...">
        <input class="half" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Indtast din e-mail...">
        <input class="half" type="text" name="mobil" placeholder="Indtast din mobilnummer...">
        <input class="half" type="text" name="antal" placeholder="Indtast antal personer...">

        <select name="dato">
          <option value="vaelg">Vælg dato</option>
        </select>

        <select name="tidspunkt">
          <option value="volvo">Vælg tidspunkt</option>
        </select>

        <textarea name="besked" placeholder="Indtast din besked..."></textarea>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send besked">

</form>
```

Comment: Write insert query within if condition

Comment: Thanks. I hate those stupid mistakes...

Comment: Also check with `isset($_POST['submit'])`

Comment: What does the isset do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your insert query is outside the if condition, so whenever you refresh the page, query gets executed. So, put inside if condition & Check with `isset()`

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $navn = $_POST['navn'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $mobil = $_POST['mobil'];
            $antal = $_POST['antal'];
            $dato = $_POST['dato'];
            $tidspunkt = $_POST['tidspunkt'];
            $besked = $_POST['besked'];


        $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'emil');
        $sql = "INSERT INTO reserver VALUES ( '', '$navn', '$email', '$mobil', '$antal', '$dato', '$tidspunkt', '$besked' )";
        $db->query($sql);

    } // complete your if here

    ?>
```

Comment: Another way to check the form submission is to use `if (!empty($_POST))` so you can avoid the input name. It is useful in case your form structure is changing and you do not want to depend on an input name.

Comment: Thanks. What does the isset() do, as the code work without it?

Comment: isset() means if this variable is set or not.